# Stop scroll of Epoxy Recyclerview on item update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, epoxy

I am new to Epoxy Recyclerview. My query is as follows.

1. I have added quite a few items in recyclerview using kotlin databinding, those consists of banners, title, grid, product carousel.
2. I have a button which adds product in wishlist and changes color of view. This functionality is working fine.
3. **What I want is not to scroll recyclerview to top and reset all views. Like if I mark 4th product in carousel as inWishlist then recyclerview must not scroll to top and carousel must not reset.**

Can anyone help me in achieving this?

here is the code
This is HomeData class.

```
data class HomeData(val listBanners : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("banner1", "banner2", "banner3"),
                val listOutCategories : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"),
                val listSaleProducts : ArrayList<Product> = arrayListOf(
                    Product(id=0, price = "$10.90"),
                    Product(id=1, price = "$11.90"),
                    Product(id=2, price = "$12.90"),
                    Product(id=3, price = "$13.90"),
                    Product(id=4, price = "$14.90"),
                    Product(id=5, price = "$105.90"),
                    Product(id=6, price = "$17.90"),
                    Product(id=7, price = "$18.90")
                ))

data class Product(val id:Int = 0, val name:String = "Product", val price:String="12.90", var inWishlist:Boolean = false)
```

This is function called to set data.

```
fun setRecyclerView(data:HomeData, isLoading : Boolean){

    binding.recyclerView.clear()

    binding.recyclerView.withModels {
        if(isLoading){
            loadList {
                id("loading")
                mainViewModel(mainActivityViewModel)
                spanSizeOverride { totalSpanCount, position, itemCount -> 1 }
            }
        }else{

            carousel {
                id("top-banners")
                withModelsFrom(data.listBanners){
                    TopBannerBindingModel_().id(it)
                }
            }

            title {
                id("out_categories_title")
                title("The Out Categories")
            }

            grid {
                id("out_cat_group")
                onBind { model, view, position ->
                    (view.dataBinding as ItemGridBinding).recyclerViewGrid.withModels {
                        data.listOutCategories.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                            outCategory {
                                id("$index-$s")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            title {
                id("on_sale_title")
                title("On Sale")
            }

            carousel {
                id("on_sale_products")
                withModelsFrom(data.listSaleProducts){
                    ProductBindingModel_()
                        .id(it.id)
                        .product(it)
                        .clickListener { model, parentView, clickedView, position ->
                            data.listSaleProducts[position].inWishlist = true
                            setRecyclerView(data, false)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Could not find a solution